# How to make outbuilding remains look aesthetically pleasing

Tags: brick

We had to knock our outbuilding down as the asbestos tiled roof had fallen in and was in a bad state of repair. We are unable to knock the wall down due to stability issues of the neighbouring structure. Any ideas on how we can make the remaining structure pleasing in our garden. Would love to remove the concrete base but afraid the vibrations will not do the wall any good?

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Before we knocked it down

[image]

Comment: Note that "aesthetically pleasing: varies by individual taste....

Comment: @keshlam ok not fugly then!

Comment: For me simply painting the whole wall a single color would achieve that...  or doing a mural.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make it a bit of a patio? Put a wooden latticework screen in front of the remaining walls, a wooden deck over the concrete floor (unless the floor can be cleaned up sufficiently), and a pergola over the top.

You could have vines climb the lattice and over the top, based in containers if the ground is not accessible.

Add a grill, a few chairs and you have a sylvan retreat.